# How to record user that browse web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to record all the user that browse into my web site, in order to store IP address. I already record the user that log in to my website, but for the user that not log in, I really have no idea how

Comment: Is this webforms or mvc?  Do you want to do server side logging or could it just be something like Google Analytics that uses javascript.

Comment: @Brandon Joyce : It is asp.net MVC with c#

Comment: @socheata - Have you tried http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/ ? and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945122/asp-net-user-activity-tracking-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a either a third party analytics tools such as Google Analytics. OR you can grab the client's IP address according to this article [ [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) ] and store it in a database.

Comment: I know how to get the IP address of the clients, but I don't know which point that I can record it. I mean, if user that ready log in , I can record it in ValidateCustomer() model. So for the user that not log in, where can I record it?

Comment: Add it as first step in your ValidateCustomer action. Any request that is coming should be logged first.

Answer (score 0):

You can log IP address and browser information in "Session_Start" in Global.asax.cs which fires every time a new user session is start. If user already logged-in then you can skip the log.

Comment: This only start this session while the user log in not for the normal user that not yet log in.